# Бьёт ошибку: sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file в коде на Python при создании погодной программы через библиотеку pyowm

Tags: python, sqlite3, pyowm, openweathermap

```py
from pyowm.owm import OWM

owm_obj = OWM('токен')
reg = owm_obj.city_id_registry()

list_of_tuples = reg.ids_for('London', matching='like')
print(list_of_tuples)
```

При создании погодного приложения через pyowm выходит ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\PROJECT2\1.21 Lesson_21.py", line 342, in <module>
    reg = owm_obj.city_id_registry()
  File "G:\PROJECT2\venv\lib\site-packages\pyowm\owm.py", line 96, in city_id_registry
    return cityidregistry.CityIDRegistry.get_instance()
  File "G:\PROJECT2\venv\lib\site-packages\pyowm\commons\cityidregistry.py", line 29, in get_instance
    return CityIDRegistry(CITY_ID_DB_PATH)
  File "G:\PROJECT2\venv\lib\site-packages\pyowm\commons\cityidregistry.py", line 21, in __init__
    self.connection = self.__decompress_db_to_memory(sqlite_db_path)
  File "G:\PROJECT2\venv\lib\site-packages\pyowm\commons\cityidregistry.py", line 52, in __decompress_db_to_memory
    src_conn = sqlite3.connect(tmpf_name)
sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file
```

Данная часть кода взята из документации за 2023 г. по pyowm
К слову, ни одна задача не выполняется, бьётся идентичная ошибка.
Данный код работает с БД, а именно reg = owm_obj.city_id_registry().
Файл БД - cities.db.bz2.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148130/discussion-on-question-by-python-ka---sqlite3-operationalerror-unabl); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вобщем у меня ошибка воспроизводится.
Система `Windows 11 eng`
`Python 3.11.4 и Python 3.10.11`
`venv/Lib/site-packages/pyowm/commons/cityidregistry.py`
вот в этом файле есть вот такой код

```py
        with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode='wb') as tmpf:
            tmpf.write(decompressed_data)
            tmpf_name = tmpf.name

            # read temp DB to memory and return handle
            src_conn = sqlite3.connect(tmpf_name)
# Ошибка происходит здесь ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

            dest_conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
            src_conn.backup(dest_conn)
            src_conn.close()
            return dest_conn
```

Если его изменить:

```py
        with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode='wb') as tmpf:
            tmpf.write(decompressed_data)
            tmpf_name = tmpf.name
            
            db_file = Path(__file__).parent / 'db.sqlite'
# Вот так --- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            db_file.write_bytes(decompressed_data)
# Вот так --- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            # read temp DB to memory and return handle

            src_conn = sqlite3.connect(db_file.absolute())
# И вот так --- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

            dest_conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
            src_conn.backup(dest_conn)
            src_conn.close()
            db_file.unlink(missing_ok=True)
            return dest_conn
```

То все работает.
Причину конечно же нужно искать это костыль, не более. Но как временная заплатка (которая скорее всего слетит при обновлении библиотеки) сгодится.

Comment: Вставила и снова ошибка! @Namerek. Мозг кипит от ошибки.)Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "..., line 545, in <module>
    reg = owm.city_id_registry()
  File "...", line 96, in city_id_registry
    return cityidregistry.CityIDRegistry.get_instance()
  File "....", line 29, in get_instance
    return CityIDRegistry(CITY_ID_DB_PATH)
  File "....", line 21, in __init__
    self.connection = self.__decompress_db_to_memory(sqlite_db_path)
  File "...", line 51, in __decompress_db_to_memory
    db_file = Path(__file__).parent / 'db.sqlite'
NameError: name 'Path' is not defined

Comment: @PYTHON_KA, Добавьте `from pathlib import Path` Лучше вверху файла и `Path(__file).parent` исправьте на `Path(__file__).parent`

Comment: Ура! Работает. Получается, если удалю и переустановлю библиотеку pyowm, всё слетит?(имею ввиду данную настройку)? Несколько дней с этой ошибкой сижу , как ежик в тумане) А, у вас данный фрагмент кода работал безошибочно? Не знаете, с чем могут быть связаны данного рода костыли? Интересно, если попробовать переустановить PyCharm, как будет...

Comment: @PYTHON_KA, с большой долей вероятности, ДА. Поскольку pip сначала удаляет старую версию, затем устанавливает новую. Не знаю как будет если переустановить PyCharm, если честно, не очень хочется переустанавливать))). И у меня повторялась ошибка та же что и у Вас иначе я бы ее и не отловил. А то что я Вам писал в комментариях - следствие некорректно заданного вопроса. )

Comment: @Namek А, поняла) Спасибо огромное за помощь!!!

Comment: Вот нашёл https://github.com/csparpa/pyowm/pull/423

Comment: @СергейКох, там это тоже костыль, справедливости ради надо отметить, что более изящный. Поскольку сама суть контекстного использования временного файла в том, что он существует только в контексте.